# Geometry Nodes: How to get Single Value at Index?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to Get Single Value at Index?

Filed at Index node not working, cos it is working with non-single values aka fields (thanx cap)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Transfer Attribute node to get a single value when using a single value as input for index or nearest position:

[image: Transfer single attribute value]

Comment: oh, the Transfer Attribute Node has converted his diamond socket to circle single-value socket after i plug it in desired location.... thanx