# Getting the vector of specific vertex indexes and performing math using geometry nodes

Tags: mathematics, geometry-nodes, vector

Getting the vector of specific vertex indexes and performing math using geometry nodes.

My goal is to get the vector of specific vertices of an object and perform math.  I'm having trouble getting the correct vector from the index. It says `(0,0,0)` no matter what index I use.

[image: img1]

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263818/geometry-nodes-how-to-get-single-value-at-index) helps? The only different thing here is the attibute wanted.

Comment: @Hulifier Yes THANKS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hulifier!!

Just in case someone else has this issue here's a simple node network.

[image: img]

Comment: Done, Thanks for cleaning house. :-)